# Remember selected panel when going back to Menu tab from Languages tab?

Tags: mmenu

I have implemented the Languages tab shown on https://mmenujs.com/documentation/addons/navbars.html BUT I would like a way to remember the position/active menu panel when going back from the Languages tab.

I am right now using the API to open both panels from icons in my visible navigation:

```
$(".mobile-lang").on("click", function() {
   api.open().openPanel( $("#languages-panel") );
});

$(".mobile-nav").on("click", function() {
   api.open().openPanel( $("#menu-panel") );
});
```

Plus I have my navbar set-up like this:

```
navbars: [{
    "position": "top",
    "type": "tabs",
    "content": [
        "<a href='#menu-panel'>" + mmenuMenu + "</a>",
        "<a href='#languages-panel'>" + mmenuLanguages + "</a>"
     ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**My solution**

My html button elements in my always visible navigation:

```
<a href="#mmenu" class="mobile-nav">Open current menu panel</a>
<a class="mobile-lang">Open languages panel</a>
```

My JS

```
         var currentMMStep = "menu-panel";

         $("#mmenu").mmenu({
            // options
            pageScroll: {
                  scroll: true,
                  update: true // pageScroll options
                },
            extensions: [
                "pagedim-black",
                "position-front",
                "position-right",
                "shadow-panels"
            ],
            navbars: [{
               "position": "top",
               "type": "tabs",
               "content": [
                  "<a href='#menu-panel' id='the-menu-panel'>" + mmenuMenu + "</a>",
                  "<a href='#languages-panel'>" + mmenuLanguages + "</a>"
               ]
            }]

        }, {
         // configuration
            clone: false,
            offCanvas: {
                pageSelector: "#page-wrap"
            }
        });

        var api = $("#mmenu").data( "mmenu" );

        $(".mobile-lang").on("click", function() {
            api.open().openPanel( $("#languages-panel") );
        });

        api.bind( "openPanel:before", function( $panel ) {
            if(!$("#languages-panel").hasClass("mm-panel_opened")){
                currentMMStep = $(".mm-panel_opened").attr("id");
                $("#the-menu-panel").attr('href', "#" + currentMMStep);
            }
        });
        api.bind( "openPanel:finish", function( $panel ) {
            if(!$("#languages-panel").hasClass("mm-panel_opened")){
                currentMMStep = $(".mm-panel_opened").attr("id");
                $("#the-menu-panel").attr('href', "#" + currentMMStep);
            }
        });

        api.bind("closeAllPanels:before", function() {
            $("#the-menu-panel").data('href', "#" + currentMMStep);
        });

        //because we alter the #menu-panel href on the Menu tab it removes the selected class when clicking the mm-navbar__title...
        $(".mm-navbar__title").on("click", function() {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
            $(".mm-navbar_tabs a:first-child").addClass("mm-navbar__tab_selected");
            }, 40);
        });
```